# Easiest way to add x-webkit-speech to the search block's input element

Tags: search, theming

I am creating a zen sub theme and I was wondering what't the quickest way to add the x-webkit-speech attribute to the search box so user's can search with their voice? I know there is a Drupal project that can modify the search for me but I would prefer to do it in my templates somewhere so the rendered output is something like...

```
<input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." type="text" x-webkit-speech id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-text">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as described in [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and [@tenken](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/3279/tenken) said, write a simple module:

```
function mymodule_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['x-webkit-speech'] = 'x-webkit-speech';
  $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['speech'] = 'speech';
}
```

also to have valid xhtml avoid valueless attribute.

Comment: just to be clear you dont need a custom module, since you asked for a "theme" solution. the hook_form functions can be called from your custom theme's `template.php` file.

Comment: I used a hybrid of your answer and tenken's. I'm marking yours as the answer because it contained most of the code I used:

function THEMENAME_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['x-webkit-speech'] = 'x-webkit-speech';
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['speech'] = 'speech';
}

Answer (score 2):

use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) on the search_form and add an [HTML attribute](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#attributes) via the `#attributes` for x-webkit-speech.