# Using a View's exposed Sort Criteria redirects to home page

Tags: 7, views

I'm using the Content: Title Sort Criteria as part of a View and I've exposed that so that site visitors can sort results.

However, when (on the front end) I hit the Sort Criteria's "Apply" button I get redirected to the home page.

The URL does retain the sort critieria information, eg: `mysite.com/?sort_by=changed&sort_order=ASC`

It's just is missing the rest of the URL - the page name. It should be `mysite.com/listing-page?sort_by=changed&sort_order=ASC`.

Looking at the filter form's action attribute, I see it is set to `action="/"`.

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use panels, and i think you are, use content panes only, not block views, etc. and make sure in views UI in middle column to set "use panel path" to yes.