# Alter a form in a block only if it is in a certain region

Tags: 7, blocks, theming, views

In my template.php I'm trying to alter a form in a views exposed block, but I only want to do this if that block is in a certain region in my theme.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Is that possible? What php code would I use?

Here is what I'm using now:

```
function cmfzen_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // change the main search form
  // see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28404/easiest-way-to-add-x-webkit-speech-to-the-search-blocks-input-element
  // see http://adaptivethemes.com/html5-placeholder-text-for-your-drupal-7-search-field
  if ($form_id == "views_exposed_form" && $form['#id'] == "views-exposed-form-site-search-page"){

    $form['site-search']['#type'] = 'searchfield';
    $form['site-search']['#attributes'] = array(
      'class' => array('search-site'),
      'placeholder' => t("I'm looking for..."),
      'speech x-webkit-speech spellcheck' => 'false',
      );
    // change form submit button

    $form['submit']['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('search-button'));
  }
}
```

Comment: You will need `hook_page_alter`

Comment: Thank you, but could you provide more of an example?

Answer (score 3):

use this code in `hook_form_alter`:

```
function cmfzen_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch($form_id){
         case 'views_exposed_form':
         $region = 'NAME_OF_A_REGION';
         $blocks = block_list($region);
         kpr($blocks);
         //if the block is in the $blocks array do the changes.
         break;
    }
}
```

using `block_list($region)` you will get the blocks that are placed in a specific region, and it returns array of block objects (for more detail visit this [page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_list/7)). Now check if the block you are looking for is in the `$blocks` array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function cmfzen_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if (block_load('views','-exp-site_search-page')->region == 'header' &&
    $form_id == "views_exposed_form" &&
    $form['#id'] == "views-exposed-form-site-search-page"
  ) {
    // alter form
  }
}
```

Change 'header' to your region name and ensure the block delta '-exp-site_search-page' is the right one.

One more solution (may be better performance) is to make your own function that queries the database for just the region of a block :

```
function mymodule_block_region($module,$delta) {
    return db_query('SELECT region FROM {block} WHERE module = :module AND delta = :delta'
    , array(':module' => $module, ':delta' => $delta))->fetchField();
}
```

And then use it instead of `block_load('views','-exp-site_search-page')->region`